# i want to write gmock google test cases for the below scenario

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

i have set of functions within the Singleton class. i want to mock a function in the singleton class. Lets take the below piece of code.The function setname() will return the string from the classyyy's setname() funciton. so here i want to test the return value.so please tell me how to write the test case for this situation.

```
class mockBtMxxx : public BTMxxx
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(setname, string(const int& id, const string& name));
};

// Test case for Setting Local Device Friendly Name.
TEST(TestBTC, GMockSetNameTest)
{
    mockBtMxxx mock_Btm;
    int id = 12345;
    string str = "Hello";
    EXPECT_CALL(mock_Btm, setname(_,_)).WillOnce(Return("Hello"));
}
```

I am getting the below errors :
error: ‘BTMxxx::BTMxxx()’ is private
gmock-actions.h:491:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘ImplicitCast_(const char*&)’

Answer (score 0):

For your first error, you need to make the constructor of your base class callable from the derived class. While you have not shown the declaration of `class BTM`, it is easy to guess that you have the constructor declared as `private` currently. I suggest making `BTMxxx::BTMxxx()` `protected` so it can be called by the mock class's default constructor.

As to your second error, the return type of `setname` is probably being deduced as `const char*`. You need to provide a `std::string` object in order for it to match the exact return type.

For a more complete picture of your problem, please provide the actual code for the `BTMxxx` class and specify what platform and compiler you are using.